# How to sort in column and row in order to get specific data in table Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Given that image below is a simple table where the variable is DATE and TYPE. I do know on how to to filter of things in terms of only using one variable.

For instance, if I create those table, I can filter the DATE such that, if I choose DATE, I can choose any date I want and will come out all data for that specific date.

I also did not know how to simultaneously filter the TYPE since type is is row section.

My question is, how to filter by using both column and row variable simultaneously. For instance, I do want to choose specific DATE and specific TYPE such as **TYPE A** and **DATE 1/01/2021** and it will shown **BLUE**

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You write "sorting", but your description suggests you actually want to do filtering. Please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry2, I do meant filtering. My bad. My english is not good.

Comment: As my suggestions in your another thread, you can use formulas to search the data according to the row and column conditions. Such as Sumproduct function, Index+Match.

Comment: There’s a distinction between “lookup” and filtering.  If you are really looking for one value, this is a lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the date you want to lookup is in cell B7, and type you want to lookup is in B8.

- The column is selected by using `MATCH(B8,C2:D2)`
- The row is selected using `MATCH(7,B4:B5)`

So the value you want is `=INDEX( C4:D5, MATCH(7,B4:B5), MATCH(B8,C2:D2) )`